# Apache MQ broker not getting create

Tags: activemq-classic, apollo

I am trying to install apache mq 1.7.1 in my windows 64 bit server , it's showing me the error while creating the broker instance as shown in the picture below.
Please note I have java 8 installed in my machine , all the path variable etc are in place , kindly help.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Apollo broker is a no longer being developed or supported.  You'd be better to go to ActiveMQ 5.14.3 or ActiveMQ Artemis v1.5.1 which are both being actively being developed and maintained.